# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes on my laptop

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, freeze

I've recently started using Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop(Lenovo G70-80) and everything is fine when I'm using my mouse But when i don't use my  mouse and use my touchpad instead, the computer completely freezes after some time. My friend is experiencing the same problem on his laptop (Not sure about the model but it's an Asus). If there is a way to fix it, please let me know, otherwise i would have to carry a mouse everyewhere i go. Thanks in advance/
best regards
Nhat Quang

Comment: Please post the output of `xinput --list`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing random freeze too. I have Lenovo Z-50, and while I ran windows 8.1 or Ubuntu (dual boot system), a random freeze could occur even if I didn't run any program at all. I found out that this happens because of electrostatic discharge when you touch the metal parts of you laptop. Try to put your laptop on a wooden or plastic surface, not a metal or glass one.

Read the last answer on this link: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Lenovo-Z50-70-random-freeze-error/td-p/1863200